# Заброшенные параметры конструктора есть ли утечка памяти?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

 Test(int n, String noName, Double d, long beta){

}

public static void main(String[]arg){

    Test test = new Test(2,"name",2.0,15124505154L);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае, память выделенная под литералы, передаваемые в аргументах конструктора, будет очищаться после окончания работы конструктора.

Объект при этом не содержит полей и размер занимаемой им памяти не будет зависеть от создаваемых литералов в конструкторе.

В памяти(если не считать основной объект Test) будет храниться только объект со строковым литералом, но так как он при следующем использовании будет браться из пула строк, то утечки памяти вызывать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, разумеется. Если на эти объекты больше не будет ссылок, их съест сборщик мусора, как обычно.